# How do I ask a question which encompasses multiple issues?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I have multiple issues with my code, but they are connected to a point that I can't separate into multiple questions. I noticed that if I post a question about all of them at the same time, the page would be filled with code.

What's a proper and clean way to post a question with multiple problems regarding my code?

Comment: Related [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120633/what-do-we-do-with-multiple-question-questions)

Comment: When you say you have "multiple issues with your code", do you mean you have multiple individual problems, or you have a single **specific** problem that is impacting or caused by multiple items in your code?  If it is the former, then the act of creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should help you narrow your code down to a the specific issue.  Which means you won't have nearly as much overlap between your questions as you think.

Comment: A clean way to post excludes non-information like "Thank you" and "So basically" in the post.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Too bad I got -2 :/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question as it stands.  At least the user here is taking the time to ask permission before they beg forgiveness.  In the context of a learning exercise, this seems fine.

Comment: Don't be discouarged by the voting. [Voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). It shouldn't harm your account. Developers knows about meta votes.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianGollhardt :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't.   You need to break them up into multiple separate questions, even of those questions are related to the same larger problem that you have.  Yes, there might be some common information repeated across those questions, when describing the context of the problem the question relates to.

Comment: This seems counter-intuitive to me, since I've always been reprimanded for repeating others (and rightly so). If I'm repeating **myself**, how is that any different?

Comment: @Kenny83 What do you mean?  If you're asking *the same question* as someone else, then yeah, that's a problem and you shouldn't do that.  If you're asking a *different* question not answered by the solution to another that happens to contain some overlap in the setup or context of the question, then that's not a problem.  Why would you think it is?

Comment: "*Why would you think it is?*" Because I've been downvoted and/or explicitly told not to do this several times. Anyway never mind; I took your advice after all and it's worked out OK so far :-)

Comment: @Kenny83 What have you been told not to do exactly?  You were told not to ask multiple questions that are different but related to each other, or you've been told not to ask *duplicate questions*, because there's a huge difference between the two.

Comment: I guess you'd call it a combination of the two. The problem is that the distinction between the two is not very clearly laid out. I have asked **what I thought** was a different question, related to another but still missing information relevant to my situation. And those questions have been marked as dupes. So my question to you was basically "how do you determine that a question is *different enough*?". Which is an incredibly subjective question, and almost impossible to answer. Therein lies the problem with so many policies in place on SO.

Comment: @Kenny83 So then why are you objecting to my assertion that you can ask multiple *different questions* on the same general topic by saying that when you asked *the same question* multiple times people told you that you shouldn't do that?  You ask different questions by ensuring that the solutions to existing questions don't solve your problem, and if it's not apparent to readers why existing solutions don't solve your problem you need to explain to them why they don't.  Since you have no duplicate questions, you appear to have deleted them, so I couldn't comment on the specifics of your case.

Comment: I think you still misunderstand me...my questions that were marked as dupes **were not the same**. At least, I didn't think so. Yes they are long gone now, so it doesn't matter. And my main reason for starting this whole conversation was so I could ask my three most-recent questions, which seem to have been different enough. So thank you for your concern, but I think we can end the conversation here.

Comment: @Kenny83 You were apparently unable to convince others that the questions were different.  But regardless, why would you claim that because your questions were considered to be the same because you were unable to distinguish them that you would go around telling everyone else that you're not allowed to ask *different questions* on the same topic?  And your assertion that you were told you're not allowed to ask different questions is clearly not true, you were told not to ask *the same question* multiple times.

Comment: **I never said you can't ask different questions, or that I was told off for doing so.** I said the complete opposite.

Comment: @Kenny83 But you did.  I posted this answer saying it's okay to ask *different questions* that are related to each other, and you said that that's not okay and that you'd been reprimanded for doing that before, which in later comments we found out was false, you were reprimanded for asking *duplicate questions* (that also were missing sufficient information to be answerable), not *different questions* that were simply related to each other.

Comment: OK perhaps I could have worded my initial comment differently to avoid your obvious misinterpretation of it. In any case, it is ludicrous for us to continue arguing in the comments (which is also discouraged if I'm not mistaken) when we actually seem to agree LOL.